# faster way to calculate the weighted mean based on rolling offset

Tags: python, pandas

I have an example df like `df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [100, 101, 99, 95, 97, 88], 'qty': [12, 5, 1, 3, 1, 3]})`. I want to calculate the rolling 5 qty average of (price * qty / qty), and the desired output is `100, 101, 100.6, 97, 96.2, 91.2`.

I don't have a good way to calculate this currently unfortunately, I have a slow way that gets close which is to calculate the cumulative sum of qty and then `df.qty_cumsum[(df.qty_cumsum<= x.qty_cumsum- 5)].argmax()` which returns the max arg of the qty - 5, then I can use this to calculate weighted average in a second step.

Thanks

Comment: I don't really get what you are asking with **rolling 5 qty average**.

Comment: so the average of the first row is of course 100, because qty is 12, the second row is 101, third row is (99 * 1 + 101 * 4)/5, fourth row is (3 * 95 + 99 * 1 + 101 * 1)/5, so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to repeat `price`, then take `rolling` with rows, and `groupby` index, taking `last`:

```
np.repeat(df['price'], df['qty']).rolling(5).mean().groupby(level=0).last()
```

Output:

```
0    100.0
1    101.0
2    100.6
3     97.0
4     96.2
5     91.2
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

P.S. And if you have large `qty` values, it would also probably make sense to make it more efficient by clipping `qty` to 5 (since there is no difference if it's 5 or 12, for example):

```
np.repeat(df['price'], np.clip(df['qty'], 0, 5)
         ).rolling(5).mean().groupby(level=0).last()
```